# Create audio file from samples of amplitude

Tags: audio, audio-recording, sampling

If I have a text file of sample amplitudes (0-26522), how can I create a playable audio file from them?

I have a vague recollection of tinkering with `.pcm` files and 8-bit samples way back in the nineties.

Is there any software to automatically create an audio file (PCM or other format) from my samples? I found [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), but I even after looking at the documentation I can't figure out if it can do what I want, and if so how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI audio workstation called [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) that lets you do this

File -> Import -> Raw Data

```
Encoding:   Signed 16-bit PCM    // even though your ints are unsigned it still works
Byte order:  little endian
Channels     1 channel mono
```

then just hit Import

to confirm this works, in a text editor I just did a ( cut N paste followed by select all paste,paste,paste,paste ) of below list of ints about 10 times to generate several thousand ints in a vertical column ... this is my toy input file ... after above Import just save by doing

File -> Export Audio

where you choose which output format  ( mp3, aac, PCM, ...)   once I did this the output mp3 is playable ... using my toy input file I did hear a sine tone

```
3
305
20294
11029
585
3
305
20294
11029
585
3
305
20294
11029
585
```