# How can sound be generated from known points?

Tags: java, audio

I have 10 lists of points (each point is time-amplitude pair), where each list belongs to known frequency

So i have a class InputValue with two fields sampleDate (long) and sampleValue (double), and 10 lists - List samples800Hz, samples400Hz and so on.

800Hz list contains about 1600 points (not fixed value because data sampler can have un-predictable delays) for each second, 400Hz list contains about 800 points for each second and so on.

How can i:

- Generate sound from list of points
- Mix several or all lists in one sound?

If i got it right, i need to resample each list to one sample rate (can java soundformat take custom sample rates like 1600, or i should use standart ones, where lowest is 8000?) and then fill samples buffer like

```
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat( (float )1600, 8, 1, true, false );
SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine( af );
sdl.open();
sdl.start();
for( int i = 0; i < 1600; i++ ) {
    buf[ 0 ] = ???
    sdl.write( buf, 0, 1 );
}
sdl.drain();
sdl.stop();
```

But how can i tell sdl that my aplitude value belongs to some frequency? and how can i mix different frequencies?

BTW, can i, instead of resampling each list, create 10 audioformats with different sample rates (1600 for 800Hz, 800 for 400Hz and so on) and later mix 10 sdls in one?

Comment: its very easy to listen to the audio generated by a list of points on a curve ...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43548080/147175

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use a wavetable for your sound generation. If you're simply just recreating an 800 Hz tone, this is easy:

```
static int sample = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
    buf[i] = samples800Hz[sample];
    sample = (sample + 1) % SAMPLES_800HZ_SIZE; 
}
```

Lets say you want to combine an 800 Hz and 1600 Hz tone... just add it together (you might have to mix the values so they don't clip):

```
static int sample1 = 0, sample2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
    // Multiply each sample by 0.5; this gives us a 50% mix between the two
    buf[i] = (samples800Hz[sample1] * 0.5) + (samples1600Hz[sample2] * 0.5);
    sample1 = (sample1 + 1) % SAMPLES_800HZ_SIZE; 
    sample2 = (sample2 + 1) % SAMPLES_1600HZ_SIZE; 
}
```

Now my answer doesn't consider how many times/number of frames your system is running its callback. You'll have to figure that out on your own. Also, if you wanted to have multiple tone generation instead of endlessly making lists, I would urge you to look up wavetable oscillators. A wavetable is basically creating one array of a tone and then adjusting the speed/phase you read the table to generate a desired frequency.

Good luck!

Comment: I still don't catch about frequency - for example my samples800Hz[0] is InputValue with some sampleDate and sampleValue = 10, wich means that at time, when sample was taken, 800Hz channel had 10dB input signal, if i simply put buf[i] = 10 - how can i tell sdl that this point belongs to 800Hz?

Comment: Sorry there might be a language barrier happening so not totally understanding you here; `samples800Hz` is an array containing the `InputValue` class? And it has two data values: `sampleDate` and `sampleValue`? If so then all you would do is is pull `sampleValue` out of the array... `samples800Hz[i].sampleValue`. Also my answer is just a guideline how you would pull data from a buffer and mix the values. I'm honestly not sure how you're writing and reading the data (you seemed to have made it very convoluted) and it kind of seems like you're really confused on the way you coded it as well.

Comment: Just to add on (because I ran out of space), are you getting confused about actual tone generation? Because from the way the question was phrased, it seems like you already have the tones in previously made buffers.

Comment: Thanks for helping! sampleValues are values after analogue to digital converter (ADC), so they are not ready-to-pull values, they hold just level information (in simple 0..255 format, where 0 belongs to 0dB and 255 is 122dB) but do not contain frequency information. So my main question is how to prepare buffer value from two digits - wave frequency and wave level for example 800Hz*100dB or 800Hz*90% of sound format level's max value

Comment: Oh ok so that's a totally different question then. If you are pulling from an external input source (microphone, line input, etc) then you'll need a FFT to analyze/discern the frequencies. There's no simple way to tell what the ADC samples are without some DSP.